# Umbraco add custom property to user

Tags: umbraco

I want to add a RTF data type to a user. This will be used as an "about me" section under an article that user wrote. I seem to be unable to add such a field/editor to a user in the back office. I seem to be able to change members, but users are seemingly locked off.

Is it correct that users are, without too much editing of the back office, completely static? Or how can I add such field? Please assist.